# Get 3 rows of data from a table group by a column

Tags: android, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table where I have data and the corresponding month. I want to fetch 3 rows of data from every month I tried with group by query, But it's not serving my purpose. Some one please help me to achieve it

```
select * 
from data 
group by Field3 
limit 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution

```
 select *  from data rv1  where id in 
( 
 select id 
   from data rv2 
    where Field3= rv1.Field3 
 order by 
 Field3 desc 
limit 2 
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with SubQuery

```
SELECT * 
     FROM data 
     WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID 
                  FROM data 
                  WHERE MONTH = 1)
```

for more refer this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm)

Comment: I want 3 element each for all the months